# How do I call one function from within another using Python?

Tags: python

My code:

```
def inner_function(self):
    x = "one"
    y = "two"

def outer_function(self):
    self.inner_function()
    print "X is %" % x
    print "Y is %" % y

outer_function()
```

I want the output to be:

```
>>> X is one
>>> Y is two
```

I think I'm not understanding the correct use of `self` in a Python method/function.

The error I'm currently returning is: `TypeError: outer_function() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
def inner_function():
    x = "one"
    y = "two"
    return x, y

def outer_function():
    x, y = inner_function()
    print "X is %" % x
    print "Y is %" % y

outer_function()
```

`self` is used for instance methods in a class, but here you're just using standalone functions.

Alternatively, for a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def printme(self):
        print(self.x)

    def mymethod(self):
        self.printme()

a = MyClass()
a.x = "One"
b = MyClass()
b.x = "Two"

a.mymethod()
b.mymethod()
```

will output:

```
One
Two
```

As you can see, you don't need to (and shouldn't) explicitly pass `self` to a method - Python passes it implicitly. When you call `a.mymethod()`, `self` will refer to `a`, and when you call `b.mymethod()`, `self` will refer to `b`. Without this mechanism, `printme()`, via `mymethod()`, would have no way of knowing which object's `x` to print.

Comment: thank you. Just so I understand, a method is when a function is associated with a class. Then, to write a method I would need to reference that method's class class which is why I'd put `self.method()` and `def method_name(self):` when I construct the methods?

Comment: You'd use `self.method()` to call a method from another method inside that same class. Outside the class you'd make an object and call the method on that, e.g. `var = MyClass()` followed by `var.method()`. The point of each method having a `self` argument is that inside the class itself, you don't know which object it might be called on, so you need a way to refer to whatever the current object is, and that's what `self` is a reference to. Standalone functions aren't associated with objects, so `self` would be out of place.